# Is the Yates' correction not necessary if I simulate the p-value of a Pearson's chi-squared test through a Monte Carlo method?

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, p-value, monte-carlo

I would like to simulate the p-value of Pearson's chi-squared tests through a Monte Carlo method. **Please correct me if I am wrong**: imagine the Yates' correction for continuity may be useful for my data (as I read on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yates%27s_correction_for_continuity), **does the simulation make it useless? Is the Yates' correction useful only when I do not simulate the p-value?**

I performed some tests using R, but I would like a bit more theoretical (not practical) answer to my question.

Comment: I doubt it is necessary. It is made for dealing with small sample sizes. The permutation test is an approximation of Fisher's exact test, which is an exact test and also deals with small samples.